# Issue adding columns to rallygridboard custom HTML

Tags: rally

What I am trying to do is set up a custom report to export a specific set of User Stories to Excel and will add a drop down to sort User Stories by Initiative.

I am having issues adding the column `'Parent'` to the grid, thought that it would be a simple task but I have hit a wall.

Any help would be great!
Thanks!!

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
extend: 'Rally.app.App',
componentCls: 'app',

              launch: function() {

               var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                        property: 'c_Priority',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: '90 days'
                    });
                    filter = filter.or({
                        property: 'c_Priority',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: '60 days' 
                    });
                     filter = filter.or({
                        property: 'c_Priority',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: '30 days'
                    });
                     filter = filter.or({
                        property: 'c_Priority',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: '120 days'
                    });
                     filter = filter.or({
                        property: 'c_Priority',
                        operator: '=',
                        value: '120+ days'
                    });                        
                    filter.toString();

                Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.TreeStoreBuilder').build({
                    models: ['User Story'],
                    autoLoad: true,
                    enableHierarchy: true,
                    filters: filter,
                }).then({
                    success: this._onStoreBuilt,
                    scope: this
                });
            },

            _onStoreBuilt: function(store) {
                var modelNames = ['User story'],
                    context = this.getContext();
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygridboard',
                    context: context,
                    modelNames: modelNames,
                    toggleState: 'grid',
                    stateful: false,

                    plugins: [
                        {
                            ptype: 'rallygridboardactionsmenu',
                            menuItems: [
                                {
                                    text: 'Export...',
                                    handler: function() {
                                        window.location = Rally.ui.grid.GridCsvExport.buildCsvExportUrl(
                                            this.down('rallygridboard').getGridOrBoard());
                                    },
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            ],
                            buttonConfig: {
                                iconCls: 'icon-export'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    gridConfig: {
                        store: store,

                        columnCfgs: [
                            'Name',
                            'ScheduleState',
                            'PlanEstimate', 
                            'c_Priority',
                            'Owner',
                            'Parent'
                              ]
                    },
                    height: this.getHeight()

                });
                console.log(store);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Parent is the user story parent.  Are you expecting it to show the portfolio item parent?  If that's the case you should use the Feature field...

Comment: @KyleMorse I am expecting to see the US's parent (a Feature). The goal is to show the Initiative (Feature.Parent.Parent). However i have tried 'Feature' also and does not populate the column. I'm not sure if i am missing something. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the dev console?  I copy/pasted your app into my subscription and the Feature column showed up fine.  Which SDK version are you using?  I used 2.1...  Another thing to check- is your lowest level portfolio item actually named Feature?